# Jquery Click Event Not Firing On First Click, but does on second click, why?

Tags: html, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I've got a jQuery code, which

```
$("a.reply").click(function() {
//code
});
```

When I click the  link with `.reply` class the first time, nothing happens.  The second time I click, the code inside the click function works.

The link is being inserted on the page using PHP from a mysql database.  so it's not being inserted dynamically.

Why is this happening?  Any solution?

**The BadASS Code:**

```
$(function(){
//TextArea Max Width
var textmaxwidth = $('#wrapper').css('width');
//Initialize Focus ids To Different Initially
var oldcommentid = -1;
var newcommentid = -2;
//End Of initialization

$("a.reply").click(function() {
        newcommentid = $(this).attr('id');
        if (newcommentid == oldcommentid)
        {
        oldcommentid=newcommentid;
        $("#comment_body").focus();
        }
        else
        {
        $('#comment_form').fadeOut(0, function(){$(this).remove()});
        var commetformcode = $('<form id="comment_form" action="post_comment.php" method="post"><textarea name="comment_body" id="comment_body" class="added_comment_body" rows="2"></textarea> <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value="0"/> <div id="submit_button"> <input type="submit" value="Share"/><input type="button" id="cancelbutton" value="Cancel"/></div></form>');
        commetformcode.hide().insertAfter($(this)).fadeIn(300);
        //
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#parent_id").attr("value", id);
        oldcommentid=newcommentid;
        //dynamicformcreation function
        dynarun();
        //
        }



        return false;
    });

        dynarun();
        
        function dynarun()
        {
        //Form Re-Run Functions
        $('#comment_body').elastic();
        texthover();
        $("#comment_form input, select, button").uniform();
        textareasizer();
        $("#comment_body").focus();
        $("abbr.timestamp").timeago();
        return false;
        }
        
        //TextArea Resizer Function
        function textareasizer(){$("#comment_body").css('max-width', textmaxwidth);return false;}
        
        //Other Miscellaneous Functions
        $('.comment-holder').hover(
        function(event) {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        },
        function(event) {
            $('.comment-holder').removeClass('highlight');
        }
        );

        function texthover()
        {
        $('.added_comment_body').hover(
            function(event) {
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlight');
            },
            function(event) {
                $('.comment-holder').removeClass('highlight');
            }
        );
        return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: Going to need more code here, please post the relevant generated HTML.

Comment: My first thought would be it comes from ["event bubbling"](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). Can you post your HTML ([use JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/) for that)?

Comment: Looks like problem is elsewhere. Does it work if you replace the code inside the click function with alert(1)?

Comment: @the_archer: do you get any error on the first click? Can you check that out with firebug or pressing Cntr+Shift+J in FF?

Comment: on first click, only this appears in console: Lost Focus: <textarea id="comment_body" rows="2" name="comment_body" style="overflow: hidden; max-width: 520px;">
Received Focus: <a id="2" class="reply" href="#comment_form">

Comment: However, the code code runs perfectly fine in Google Chrome, but doesn't work in FF and IE

Comment: Do you have any other jquery objects on that page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a longshot, but are you running some sort of tracking script?  Like webtrends or coremetrics (or even some of your own script, that's globally looking for all clicks)?  I ran into a similar problem a while ago, where the initial-click was being captured by coremetrics.  Just a thought.

Comment: hmm...good thinking.  I have tons of script working in the background.  Gonna disable them and see.

Comment: you nailed it man.  There was a form styling script I was using.  Removing the script does the trick.  Now everything works.

Comment: the script in question was jquery uniform.  http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/  I wish I could kick that developer in the ass.

Comment: @yoda a common problem with very little explanation of it on the web O_O  You can't believe the amount of I was sitting here researching and pulling my hair out.

Comment: @True North Creative thanks once more...wasn't such a longshot with your guess huh... :p

Comment: @the_archer: actually there's lots of information about it, but since most people having trouble with it have no substancial knowlenge of javascript, it's hard to google for a solution.

Comment: @yoda  you're right.  It's only my 3 weeks into javascript :)

Answer (score 2):

Does it still happen if you comment out all your code and simply have an `alert("hi")` inside the click function?

**Update**

I think Sarfaz has the right idea, but I would use the document ready function like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.reply").click(function() {
    //code
  });
});
```

Comment: nope, even with document ready and only a simple click function with an alert inside it does not work.

Comment: that approach is essentially the same.

Comment: If it works the second time, document.ready isn't likely to help here, though it is a good practice to use it.

Comment: isn't $(function(){ supposed to be a shorthand for document ready? :p

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into same problem and I resolved my problem by removing:

```
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
```

you can use bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Use Inline CSS for hiding div and use JS/jQuery to show . This way Jquery Click Event will Fire On First Click

```
     <div class="about-block">
      <div class="title">About us</div>
        <div class="" id="content-text" style="display:none;">
            <p>Show me.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

        <script>     
         var x = document.getElementById("content-text");
             jQuery( '.about-block' ).click(function() {
               if (x.style.display === "none") {
                  x.style.display = "block";             

                } else {
                  x.style.display = "none";
                }
             });
      </script>
```